# Vertical Scroll Bar that moves content sideways

Tags: ipad, scroll

First time post on StackOverFlow.com, a shame as I am considered to be a computer science student. First and foremost, thank you all so much for the help you have already provided me via other's inquiry answering my own questions. Today I have my own real question which like this post's title may be hard to understand. I however like a challenge.

```
</introduction>
```

ABSTRACT: Using the content of the website somethingmedia.co on the artist / philosophy pages; create a more user friendly display with special consideration of mobile devices.

METHOD: Alter blocked 'div' content to be virtually inline and allow side scrolling. Please visit here for a clear representation to [[demo]](http://code.comunicatek.com/plugins/tekslider/index.html) and see below for explanation[a]

ALTERATION: While allowing for touch and hold sensitivity options as seen in [method] also allow the scrolling to occur with a mouse wheel. Please see [[demo2]](http://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/) and visit explanation[b] below.

FUNCTIONALITY: In addition to the [method] and [alteration], allow scrolling to also occur upon users' movement of the pages scroll bar itself. **Except** (and here is the tricky part), make the scroll bar *vertical*, yet only move the content left and right. Scroll bar only visible on non mobile devices (i.e. PC / Laptops / Macintosh / etc).

CONCLUSION: I like making websites and though I have never taken a formal class for websites (since the 6th grade) I continue to learn new things based on what I find unique and interesting. Therefore, I am curious to know if there is a way to implement this design in a simple and elegant fashion. Though my computer science experience is limited to Java and Python in school, I have independent experience in CSS, HTML, Java Script and a bit of CGI. If you're up for the challenge with me I ask you: "What is my first step?"

```
</concept>
```

explanation[a]: code.comunicatek.com/en/tekslider_a_touch_focused_slider.html

explanation[b]: css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

Comment: are you trying to write you question as a formal report?? i feel it harder to understand...

Answer (score 0):

The question's a little confusing, but assuming what you really mean is, "How can I have a page that uses vertical scroll bars to scroll the page horizontally," I'd try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>Vertizontal Scrolling</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#page-scroll').height($('#page-wrap').outerWidth());
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                $('#page-wrap').css('left',-1 * $(window).scrollTop());
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css" style="display: none !important;">
        #page-wrap {
            position:fixed;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            z-index:10;
        }
        #page-scroll {
            z-index:1;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>  

    <div id="page-scroll">
        <!--- intentionally empty --->
    </div>

    <div id="page-wrap">
        <!--- really wide content goes here --->
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```